# Python - Запуск CGI скприпта

Tags: python, сервер, cgi

никак не получается запустить `cgi` скрипт на сервере..

```
#!/bin/env python3
print("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()
print("<h1>Hello world!</h1>")
```

ls:

```
 root@server:/var/www# ls -l cgi-bin
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 107 окт 19 17:58 1.py
```

лог:

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
770.70.802.360 - - [19/Oct/2016 18:38:26] code 403, message CGI script is   not a plain file ('/cgi-bin/')
770.70.802.360 - - [19/Oct/2016 18:38:26] "GET /cgi-bin/ HTTP/1.1" 403 -
770.70.802.360 - - [19/Oct/2016 18:38:37] "GET /cgi-bin/1.py HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 1135, in run_cgi
os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/cgi-bin/1.py'
77.87.102.36 - - [19/Oct/2016 18:38:37] CGI script exit status 0x7f00
```

сервер запускаю так:

```
python3 -m http.server --cgi
```

при попытке открыть файл через браузер, он предлагает скачать этот файл..

права стоят везде `777`.. так же стоит и группа `www-data` везде... что это может быть? почему `Permission denied`?

Comment: Есть у вас `/bin/env`? Лучше явный путь указать `/usr/bin/python3`. Попробуйте явно как `www-data` пользователь выполнить скрипт `sudo -u www-data /var/www/cgi-bin/1.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте права не только на файле, но и на директориях выше по дереву.
Достаточно "x" на директориях для того, чтобы пользователь мог добраться до файла и "r" на самом файле чтобы смог открыть его.